# Spark submit failed due to exception in ZooKeeperPersistenceEngine

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zookeeper, spark-structured-streaming

Spark submit fails due to an exception caused in ZooKeeperPersistenceEngine.
Tested the jar deployment in my local environment however when I try to push it to the cluster it fails.

Spark: 2.4.0
Zookeeper: 3.4.14
Scala: 2.11

```
./spark-submit --class com.test.Main --deploy-mode cluster --master spark://10.1x.1xx.xx:27077 /tmp/test_jars/stp.jar
```

```
19/09/10 18:52:16 INtestClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server 10.1x.1xx.xx:2181, sessionid = 0x10020111fa00001, negotiated timeout = 40000
19/09/10 18:52:16 INFO ConnectionStateManager: State change: CONNECTED
19/09/10 18:52:18 INFO Master: Registering worker 10.1x.1xx.xx:28088 with 1 cores, 4.0 GB RAM
19/09/10 18:52:25 INFO Master: Registering worker 10.1x.1xx.xx:28088 with 1 cores, 4.0 GB RAM
19/09/10 18:52:32 INFO Master: Registering worker 10.1x.1xx.xx:28088 with 1 cores, 4.0 GB RAM
19/09/10 18:52:39 INFO Master: Registering worker 10.1x.1xx.xx:28088 with 1 cores, 4.0 GB RAM
19/09/10 18:52:42 INFO Master: Registering worker 10.1x.1xx.xx:28088 with 1 cores, 4.0 GB RAM
19/09/10 18:52:46 INFO Master: Registering worker 10.1x.1xx.xx:28088 with 1 cores, 4.0 GB RAM
19/09/10 18:52:49 INFO ZooKeeperLeaderElectionAgent: We have gained leadership
19/09/10 18:52:49 WARN ZooKeeperPersistenceEngine: Exception while reading persisted file, deleting
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.deploy.master.WorkerInfo; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7036178881785247710, local class serialVersionUID = -427782398096880289
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:689)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1903)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1772)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.ZooKeeperPersistenceEngine.org$apache$spark$deploy$master$ZooKeeperPersistenceEngine$$deserializeFromFile(ZooKeeperPersistenceEngine.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.ZooKeeperPersistenceEngine$$anonfun$read$2.apply(ZooKeeperPersistenceEngine.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.ZooKeeperPersistenceEngine$$anonfun$read$2.apply(ZooKeeperPersistenceEngine.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.ZooKeeperPersistenceEngine.read(ZooKeeperPersistenceEngine.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.PersistenceEngine$$anonfun$readPersistedData$1.apply(PersistenceEngine.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.PersistenceEngine$$anonfun$readPersistedData$1.apply(PersistenceEngine.scala:86)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:320)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.PersistenceEngine.readPersistedData(PersistenceEngine.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(Master.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcV$sp(Inbox.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher$MessageLoop.run(Dispatcher.scala:221)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
19/09/10 18:52:49 WARN ZooKeeperPersistenceEngine: Exception while reading persisted file, deleting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleared the temp folder created by zookeeper and the issue got resolved. Also there was connection error with the worker nodes due to RPC environment setting